# Connecting Looker to Snowflake with SSO enabled

Tags: single-sign-on, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, looker

Hi we're enabling federated authentication in snowflake - that means we'll no longer be allowing using user and password.
Everything that connects to snowflake can use a .pem certificate but looker.
There is no such option, you can either use login/pass or oAuth.
Snowflake support suggested ssh tunnel but I don't see how this might help

Comment: What IdP are you using for SSO?  Is there an issue using OAuth?

Comment: Jumpcloud. With oauth you'd need to create account for every user in looker in snowflake as well right? not sure if I want that...

Comment: There is no difference between OAuth and SSO in this regard.  You'd either use a service account or individual user accounts either way.

Comment: Yes you are right. I've understood it differently at the beginning. So We've connected to snowlake using oauth but then there is a new problem. PDT (persistent derived table) won't work using oauth :(

Answer (score 0):

Brandon with JumpCloud here — there's actually an ongoing discussion about integrating JumpCloud with Snowflake, in the #sso channel of our public Slack workspace. One admin has achieved success and is offering help. If that sounds relevant, feel free to join in — https://join.slack.com/t/jumpcloudlounge/shared_invite/zt-esobabj4-Ytqy4ZSTo6ZONoALoGHAKA.

Comment: hi. We've managed to connect the jumpcloud to snowflake. Problem is more on looker -> snowflake side